# Congratulations, Anna Lear!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Good news, everyone!

Everyone's favorite Programmers mod, [Anna Lear](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/226/anna-lear), has joined the [Stack Exchange Team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) as a Community Manager, where she'll be working her magic across the network.

Anna's been an active user here since the beginning, and a dedicated moderator since our first elections way back in January of 2011.

Unfortunately for us, this news means she'll be stepping down as a moderator here on Programmers (but hopefully she'll still be stopping by frequently anyway!).

We all wish Anna the best of luck on her new role, and thank her for her service here!

Comment: +1: Thanks, Mark. It really can't be overstated. Anna was the best moderator and she will be sorely missed.

Answer (score 33):

Thanks for the kind words, Mark.

I'll definitely still be dropping by to answer questions and the like. :)

Comment: Congratulations, Anna!

Comment: Nooooo Anna don't leave us!

Comment: Congratulations!  Good luck in your new role.

Comment: @Anna Lear: Just wanted to say thank you for all that you've done so far, and that I've always found your feedback to go above and beyond; which at least to me, has made a huge, huge difference in my opinion of SE. Cheers!

Comment: @blunders Thanks!

Comment: @maple_shaft Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, congratulations!  When do they make the big blog.stackoverflow.com announcement about this? :P

Comment: Very well deserved.  Much luck in your new role.

Comment: Congratulations! All the best  to you Anna!

Answer (score 9):

Wow!

Congratulations Anna!

---

Anna was the best programmers.se moderator **by a long shot.**

She always tempered her powers as a moderator, and bothered to try to understand why people posted what they did.

---

Anna - You're leaving big shoes to fill. I'm probably speaking for many others, but I sincerely hope that somebody with comparable wisdom and prudence fills your shoes.

In closing, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 7):

As it's almost a year since our first election there *probably* won't be any special arrangements made to replace Anna. What will *probably* happen is that an extra moderator space will be up for election when the election does come round.

So start thinking whether you want to be part of the moderation team.

This is an informed guess on my part and could well be superseded by official announcements.

**NOTE:** Under normal circumstances being a moderator is a lifetime appointment, you carry on until you don't want to do the job any more or get hired by Stack Exchange. There have been occasions where moderators have been asked to step down.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the info, Chris. I am going to go out of my way to back a candidate who intends to moderate like Anna did.

Answer (score 3):

---

**Moderators Diary**

---

- Questions they **Correct**,
- Answers they **Inspect**,
- Improvements they **Direct**,
- Based on the **Subject**,
- Ultimately making the website **Perfect**.

---

*I have been an active member for the past two months and I really like the quality of posts that is maintained [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and thats' because of **good moderators.***

From my experience in these two months, many questions have her touch of quality as **corrections or answers** and I really appreciate her for her ***dedication***.

**Anna - Congratulations and Best of luck for your new role at Stack Exchange Team!**

Answer (score -3):

In the [Stack Exchange Podcast #06](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-06/) (at the end) they talk about the role of a new SE "community evangelism team". (Not sure if this is the same as what a "community manager" does)

Comment: That's a good question. Why did you post it as an answer instead of a question? You should ask it on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)...

Comment: @knb No, that's [a different team](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/welcome-chaos/). They are primarily focused on external site promotions. Community managers support communities and moderators internally within the network, monitor private betas, etc.